# How to apply a formatting rule to a whole row based on a cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'd like to Bottom Border to a whole row where a certain cell is non-empty. I have managed to do that by using conditional formatting formula `=$A2<>""` and applied that to the whole column.

My problem with that solution however is that it only creates the border only for the single cell and I want the whole row to have the border. It doesn't look like there is anything can be done from the "Format Cells" dialog.

**EDIT**:

Below is what I have at the moment:

[image]

And this is what I want to achieve (assume that the bottom border goes until the end of the row):
[image]

This is the conditional formatting rule that I applied:
[image]
Any other way to achieve that?

Comment: can you please insert some screenshots and explain there what exactly happens, and what is your goal? it isn't clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the formatting for every row to be based on the value in cell `A2`? If so, just select the rows you want to format, and use this conditional-formatting formula: `=$A$2<>""`.

If instead you want each row's formatting to be based on the value in that row's `A` column, just use the conditional-formatting formula you already mentioned: `=$A2<>""`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I need to base the formatting on values of multiple rows, all of them in the first column though. The formula I have mentioned works however I have to admit I do not fully understand how as it formats all the rows where the first cell is not empty(which is what I need). My problem is that currently, only the first cell in a row gets the bottom border and I would like the border to affect the whole row.

Comment: Your question says "where a certain cell is non-empty", and does not mention multiple values. Could you please edit the question so as to be a bit more clear, and also provide some sample data along with the results you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: That's correct but what I also say is that I want to apply the formatting to the **whole row** based on that cell value.

Comment: Right, and my answer does indicate how to conditionally-format a whole row, so I'm a bit confused. If I'm missing something, please edit your question so I can understand what it is. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer discusses the **condition** that will trigger the formatting. I ask about how the formatting is applied to a certain area. So at the moment I only have a single cell underlined. I want the whole row underlined. I am sorry but I fail to find an answer to that in your reply. Thanks.

Comment: My answer also says "select the rows you want to format" (that's your "certain area"). If you do so, and then apply conditional formatting using one of the formulas I mentioned, the entire rows will be formatted. If that's not what you want, then please follow the suggestion made by both me and @Máté, and show us what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't have any effect. I added few screenshots to my question.

Comment: Don't reference columns in the "Applies to" value. Change the "Applies to" value to `=$2:$1048576`. The current value shows that you most likely pressed Ctrl+A to select all the cells, which is not the same as selecting the rows, as I had mentioned (although I didn't know you were trying to select all of them).